# Lanch and kill script monitor via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, kill-process

I have a bash script that monitor some system statistic.

I need to run the script on several machine, all at the same time.

I would like to launch the script on all the machine and when the operation I want to monitor is over I need to stop the logging.

To launch the script I can use ssh, but I have no idea how to stop it.

Comment: if certain condition is met why shouldn't you something like `kill -9 $$` from within you script?

Comment: you may dump the pid to a file `echo $!>xyz.pid` from within your launched script. then later use `ssh -q machine "cat xyz.pid | xargs kill"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to kill script knowing only its name you can try:

```sh
kill -9 `ps -e | grep NAME_OF_SCRIPT | cut -d ' ' -f 3`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ ! -z $(pidof process_name_you_wish_to_monitor) ]
do
#do what you wish to do here or wait certain number of seconds.
#I would better wait as I have nothing to do ;)
sleep 10s
done
```

**Edit**

I initially had `kill -9 $$` at the end of the script but removed it as it is redundant. The process will end gracefully anyway. Doesn't it?